# What is the difference between the solr PHP clients?

Tags: php, solr, client

I found Solarium and that one http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/.

But I don't really know what are the differences between both, what PHP framework do they use and which is the best option.

I would really appreciate any tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clients are clients and primarily do the same thing - allow you to interact with the Solr server. Different clients might do it in different way, provide better or worse API or have different kind of issues.

Solr protocol is quite simple so theoretically you don't need any client. You can use CURL and make direct calls.

I would recommend using PHP extensions `http://pecl.php.net/package/solr`. It's faster because it's build in into PHP (obviously it won't make the server to work faster).

If you are going to use Solr4 (you should) the current version of the extension on pecl will not work ;-). You can use my patch https://github.com/lukaszkujawa/php-pecl-solr which will go into the stable release in the future. The difference is you have an extra switch in the client constructor:

```
$client = new SolrClient($options, "4.0");
```

That should care of differences between 3.x and 4.x

Comment: Thanks for your response. Anyway I think that a PHP client is not needed. Just accessing to solr with curl using the solr URL (http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&indent=true&wt=json) and after retrieving all the data, it's the same. I don't see any advantage of using a php client than doing it on that way.